# Using \g@addto@macro in a loop

Tags: macros, expansion, loops, strings, write

I am confused when using `\g@addto@macro` in a loop. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\@initial[1]{#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand\initial[1]{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
    \@initial{\firstletter}}

\newcounter{authors@count}
\newcommand\authors[2]{
    \stepcounter{authors@count}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @author@first\arabic{authors@count}\endcsname{#1}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @author@last\arabic{authors@count}\endcsname{#2}
}

\newcounter{i}
\def\authorsliststring{}
\def\authorslist{%
    \whiledo{\value{i} < \value{authors@count}}{%
        \stepcounter{i}%
        \@nameuse{@author@last\thei}\space% for test only
        \initial{\@nameuse{@author@first\thei}}.% for test only
        \g@addto@macro\authorsliststring{%
            \@nameuse{@author@last\thei} 
            \initial{\@nameuse{@author@first\thei}}.}%
        \ifthenelse{\thei = \theauthors@count}{}
            {,\space% for test only
                \g@addto@macro\authorsliststring{, }%
        }%
    }
}

\newcommand\writetoc{
    \newoutputstream{txt}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{txt}
    \addtostream{txt}{\authorsliststring}
    \closeoutputstream{txt}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\authors{Alex}{Andersson}
\authors{Barbara}{Brown}
\authors{Charles}{Chaplin}

\authorslist

\authorsliststring

\writetoc

\end{document}
```

When developing my class, it is convenient for me to write separately the First and Nast Name in separate variables using repeated `\authors` commands. Later, using a separate `\authorslist` macro, I generate `\authorsliststring` string as Last Name and the first char of First Name (it's a long explanation here why I need to do this in a separate `\authorslist` command and why I need `\initial` command in this way, but I need it like this). The string `\authorsliststring` is then used in the right places in the class and written to the file to generate TOC later from other TeX file. I need to get the same in `\authorsliststring` and in the file - "Andersson A., Brown B., Chaplin C."

However, on the screen I see:

[image: 1]

and I get in the file:

`Chaplin \initial {Charles}., Chaplin \initial {Charles}., Chaplin \initial {Charles}.`

Besides, I do not understand how to write to the file not `\initial {Charles}`, but `C.`.

Comment: To see what's happening, write `\show\authorsliststring` after setting a bunch of `\authors`. You'll see that macro doesn't actually have any of the author's names in it, and in all cases refer to the author by index `\thei`. That `\thei` points to whatever the last value of `i` is, hence all the same (last) authors being listed. You should *expand* the value of `\thei` so that it stores the actual number rather than the macro `\thei`. That's one option.

Comment: Is there a need to write the `\authorsliststring` to a file?

Comment: @Werner Yes, it's necessary

Comment: @Crosfield What is the purpose of `\@initial` ?

Comment: @UlrichDiez In my class this function is much more complicated. It takes as a parameter any number of space-separated words, including those in languages containing Slavic characters, and cuts out the first letters in each. It uses functions from `xstring`. Here I have simplified it as much as possible.

Comment: @Crosfield In your MWE: Why is `\@initial` applied to `\firstletter` which in turn comes from applying `\StrLeft`?  In your real-life-scenario: Is `\@initial` applied to `\firstletter`? Is `\firstletter` the result of `\@initial`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez You're right, in my MWE using the macro `\@initial` is redundant and you can just write `\DeclareRobustCommand\initial[1]{\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]\firstletter}`. I just tried to find a trick to get the 'final' value in the file and forgot to remove this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The rôle of the macro-combination `\initial`-`\@initial` is not exactly clear to me.

Seems `\initial` is a macro-mechanism which internally uses `\@initial` and `\StrLeft` and at some point defines the macro `\firstletter` to expand to the first letter of the first name of the author.

As long as within your `\authorslist`-recursion/`\whiledo`-recursion you properly separate which actions are expandable and which are not—e.g., `\StrLeft` (and thus also `\initial`) is not, you can combine the trick of (ab?)using `\romannumeral` for keeping TeX triggering expansion until encountering `\UD@stopromannumeral` with the trick of exchanging macro arguments in order to have TeX line up the tokens of a `\g@addto@macro`-directive for adding a name to `\authorsliststring` in one go:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%

% Assume \initial is a function/macro-mechanism which at some point defines the macro 
% \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter to deliver the first letter of the first name.
% ( \initial itself probably is not fully expandable, e.g., due to calling \StrLeft
%   or ehatever,  which in turn is not fully expandable. In any case in the end
%   the macro \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter is defined. )
\newcommand\ScratchmacroForFirstLetter{}%
\@ifdefinable\initial{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\initial[1]{\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\ScratchmacroForFirstLetter]}%
}%

\newcounter{authors@count}
\newcommand\authors[2]{%
    \stepcounter{authors@count}%
    \global\@namedef{@author@first\arabic{authors@count}}{#1}%
    \global\@namedef{@author@last\arabic{authors@count}}{#2}%
}

\newcounter{i}%
\newcommand*\authorsliststring{}%
\newcommand*\authorslist{%
    \ifnum\value{i} < \value{authors@count}% Why \whiledo if the recursion can be done without? ;-)
        \stepcounter{i}%
        % ==============================================================================================
        % Typeset the name of the author:
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % - Typeset the first name and a space:
        \@nameuse{@author@last\thei} %
        % - Somehow get the first letter of the first name of the author into the macro
        %   \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter - this is the job of \initial:
        \initial{\@nameuse{@author@first\thei}}%
        % - Apply  \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter for typesetting the first letter of the first name of
        %   the author, trailed by a dot:
        \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter.%
        % - Probably typeset a comma and a space:
        \ifthenelse{\thei = \theauthors@count}{}{, }%
        % ==============================================================================================
        % Add the name of the author to the macro \authorsliststring:
        % ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %  - Somehow get the first letter of the first name of the author into the macro
        %    \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter - this is the job of \initial:
        \initial{\@nameuse{@author@first\thei}}%
        %  - From now on everything else can be done by means of expansion-methods -
        %    do some argument-exchanging-trickery via \UD@Exchange for lining up the tokens within
        %    the brace-group which encloses the last argument of the \g@addto@macro-directive;
        %    within the brace-group which encloses the last argument of the \g@addto@macro-directive
        %    use \romannumeral for keeping expansion going until TeX sees \UD@stopromannumeral:
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\authorsliststring\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral
          \ifnum\value{i}=\value{authors@count}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi    
          {\UD@Exchange{}}{\UD@Exchange{, }}%
          {%
            \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
               \ScratchmacroForFirstLetter.%
            }{%
              \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
              \csname @author@last\thei\expandafter\endcsname\@firstofone{ }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
    \expandafter\authorslist\fi
}

\newoutputstream{txt}%
\newcommand\writetoc{%
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{txt}%
    \addtostream{txt}{\authorsliststring}%
    \closeoutputstream{txt}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\authors{Alex}{Andersson}
\authors{Barbara}{Brown}
\authors{Charles}{Chaplin}

\setcounter{i}{0}%
\authorslist

\texttt{\vrule\string\authorsliststring=\meaning\authorsliststring\vrule}

\authorsliststring

\writetoc

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To be honest, to me this seems unnecessarily complicated. Using expl3 instead of xstring's `\StrLeft`, the first letter of the first name can probably be obtained via `\str_head_ignore_spaces:n`, which is expandable:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N  \__MyStuff_Authors_clist
\cs_new_protected:Npn \authors #1#2 
  {
    \clist_gput_right:Nx \__MyStuff_Authors_clist 
                         {{#2~\str_head_ignore_spaces:n{#1}.}}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \authorslist 
  {  \clist_use:Nnnn \__MyStuff_Authors_clist {,~}{,~}{,~}  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newoutputstream{txt}%
\newcommand\writetoc{%
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{txt}%
    \addtostream{txt}{\authorslist}%
    \closeoutputstream{txt}%
}

\begin{document}

\authors{Alex}{Andersson}
\authors{Barbara}{Brown}
\authors{Charles}{Chaplin}

\noindent
\authorslist

\writetoc

% Let's see the content of  \jobname.txt - with older LaTeX-releases
% you might need to add   \usepackage{verbatim}  to the preamble for
% this to work out, but seems the package  newfile  already does that
% for you:

\verbatiminput{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, `\thei` needs to be expanded in the argument of `\g@addto@macro`.  Here, I do that by saving the fully expanded definition of `\thei` as `\Thei` (several expansions are required), and then using enough `\expandafter`s (shorthanded as `\z`) in the definition to replace occurrences of `\Thei` with its expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\@initial[1]{#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand\initial[1]{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
    \@initial{\firstletter}}

\newcounter{authors@count}
\newcommand\authors[2]{
    \stepcounter{authors@count}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @author@first\arabic{authors@count}\endcsname{#1}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @author@last\arabic{authors@count}\endcsname{#2}
}

\newcounter{i}
\def\authorsliststring{}
\def\Al{@author@last}
\def\Af{@author@first}
\let\z\expandafter
\def\authorslist{%
    \whiledo{\value{i} < \value{authors@count}}{%
        \stepcounter{i}%
        \edef\Thei{\thei}%
%        \@nameuse{\Al\thei}\space% for test only
%        \initial{\@nameuse{\Af\thei}}.% for test only
        \z\z\z\g@addto@macro\z\z\z\authorsliststring\z\z\z{\z\z\z%
            \@nameuse\z\z\z{\z\z\z\Al\z\Thei\z}\z\ \z 
            \initial\z{\z\@nameuse\z{\z\Af\Thei}}.}%
        \ifthenelse{\thei = \theauthors@count}{}
            {%,\space% for test only
                \g@addto@macro\authorsliststring{, }%
        }%
    }
}

\newcommand\writetoc{
    \newoutputstream{txt}
    \openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{txt}
    \addtostream{txt}{\authorsliststring}
    \closeoutputstream{txt}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\authors{Alex}{Andersson}
\authors{Barbara}{Brown}
\authors{Charles}{Chaplin}

\authorslist

\authorsliststring

\writetoc

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Very useful. I know `xstring` commands are not expandable. Can you tell how to write the final result to the file as `Andersson A., Brown B., Chaplin C.`, but not `Andersson \initial {Alex}., Brown \initial {Barbara}., Chaplin \initial {Charles}.`.

Comment: @Crosfield Since `\initial` is not expandable, there is no way to do this, unless you reformulate your approach avoiding the `xstring` commands.

Comment: I got it. Just I thought that there is some trick that will allow to return the 'final' value through another function and this 'final' value will be just a string of characters.